# HTTP Transport and HTTP Request

Tags: java, json, httprequest

I'm trying to fetch a JSON from an API using HTTP Request. However, I'm still unable to set up the request. Here is my current code

```
HttpTransport transport = new HttpTransport() {
    @Override
    protected LowLevelHttpRequest buildRequest(String s, String s1) throws IOException {
        return null;
    }
};
```

I was forced to create an HTTP Transport object, but I have no idea what to put in it, documentation doesn't give me any clues too

```
@Override
public void action(String[] args, MessageReceivedEvent event) {
    HttpRequest request=new HttpRequest(transport,"GET");
    request.setUrl(url);
    request.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    try {
        request.execute();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

url is already containing the Json Web Token used for Authorisation.

However, when initializing the HttpRequest, it gives me the following error:

```
'HttpRequest(com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport, java.lang.String)' is not public
in 'com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest'.
Cannot be accessed from outside package
```

This error does even appear, when I clear the brackets:

```
HttpRequest request=new HttpRequest();
```

Does anyone know, what I'm doing wrong?

Update: I've fixed my code, but still get an error:

```
HttpTransport transport = new ApacheHttpTransport();
    HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = transport.createRequestFactory();
    try {
        HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
        request.execute();
        System.out.println(request.getContent());
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The error I get shown is:

```
avax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Edit: Even if I use the example below, it returnes this error

Comment: _HttpTransport_ is an abstract class, so you need to use one of the concrete implementations of it instead, e.g. _ApacheHttpTransport_.

see https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport

Comment: I've replaced HttpTransport with ApachHttpTransport, doesn't seem to change anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means the `HttpRequest` constructor is protected to call. You have to use `HttpRequestFactory` factory to create a `HttpRequest` instance.

To get `HttpRequestFactory` you have to had `HttpTransport` see https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport

```
HttpTransport transport = new ApacheHttpTransport();
HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = transport.createRequestFactory();
HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
HttpResponse response = request.execute();
     try {
       // process the HTTP response object
           InputStream is = response.getContent();
           try {
               // Process the input stream..
           } finally {
               is.close();
           }
     } finally {
       response.disconnect();
     }
```

> Never tried the example hope it will work.

Comment: Seems to work.
But two questions:
1. Do I have to put the URL as _requestBody_ ? You've putted a JSON in it, which doesn't shows this clear.
2. Where is the JSON stored afterwards? In _transport_ ?

Comment: My bad that was POST request.  You want to call GET so you don't have to provide body at all. I changed the example.

Comment: I've added your code and added `System.out.println(request.getContent());` in order to see the response. But the response is _null_ . When I enter the URL directly in the browser, it works

Comment: Well, you have to call `request.execute()` that returns you `response` where content beholds.

Comment: `request.execute()` gives me an error. I've updated the question with more information

Comment: Ohh man, shall I google for you? :) http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomSSL.java

Comment: thanks for your effort, but as it doesn't help (there is a libary used, which I cannot find) and is actually a complete new question, I will stop commenting here